# AttributeError for sarimax from statsmodels.tsa.statespace

Tags: python, statsmodels

I am trying to use

```
model_S = statespace.sarimax.SARIMAX(df['lnpd'], trend='n', order=(12,1,12), seasonal_order=(1,1,1,12))
```

Shows error:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'sarimax'

I just updated `statsmodels` to 0.8.0 and had no problem importing `statspace`. Does anyone have the same problem?

Thanks.

Comment: how do you import statespace?

Answer (score 4):

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(..)
```